# Reference for submultiplicativity of length of tensor product

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a reference, in the form of a textbook, that contains proofs of following statements.

**NOTE:** I am NOT looking for the proofs, I am looking for a reference! Proofs of these statements are elementary. In fact, I need a reference to avoid writing the proofs. I just want to be able to refer somewhere for the proofs. I am sure these must be somewhere. Surprisingly, I cannot find them in standard textbooks that I know!!

**1.** Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a local homomorphism of Noetherian local rings with residue fields $k_R$ and $k_S$, respectively, and assume that $[^fk_S:k_R]<\infty$. If $N$ is an $S$-module of finite length, then $^fN$ is an $R$-module of finite length, and 
$\ell_R(^fN)=[^fk_S:k_R]\cdot\ell_S(N)$.

**2.** Let $f:(R,\mathfrak{m})\rightarrow(S,\mathfrak{n})$ be a homomorphism of Noetherian local rings such that $\ell_S(S/f(\mathfrak{m})S)<\infty$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module of finite length. Then

$\ \ \ \ $ **a)** $M\otimes_RS$ is an $S$-module of finite length and $\ell_S(M\otimes_R S)\leq\ell_S(S/f(\mathfrak{m})S)\cdot\ell_R(M)$.

$\ \ \ \ $ **b)** If in addition $f$ is *flat*, then $\ell_S(M\otimes_R S)=\ell_S(S/f(\mathfrak{m})S)\cdot\ell_R(M)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at lemmas 45.12 and 45.13 of the following: http://www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/algebra.pdf

This comes from the Stacks open source textbook project, you can browse their chapters here:
http://www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/browse.html

Comment: Thanks Parsa! Is it customary to include Stacks Project as a reference in a paper? Have you seen that in papers?

Comment: You're welcome Mahdi.  I personally haven't seen such a reference myself, but references to online work are increasingly common nowadays.  Given that there is a page that describes how to reference the Stacks Project, http://math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=1055 , I am guessing that it's not uncommon either.